# custom placement of buttons in dialog box - jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I wanted to move the buttons added to my dialog box to either top or left how can this be done i'm using jquery ui. When ok is added it shows up at extreme right end can this be placed around ?

```
$(function() {
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal : true,
    resizable : false,
    buttons : {
        ok:function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To place the buttons left/center/right aligned, disable the floating and adjust the `text-align` property accordingly:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
   float: none;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
     text-align: center; /* left/center/right */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/zV7Us/)**

---

This is the markup for the buttons:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
        <!-- the buttons are here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The default css specifies:

- `text-align: left;` for the element `.ui-dialog-buttonpane`
- `float:right` for the element `.ui-dialog-buttonset`

Comment: thanks didier! can i specify something like left:25px for the button to move it ?

Comment: You're welcome. Once you have disabled the floating, you can do whatever you want with margins, left/right, etc.

Comment: i changed the float:none and put left and margin value doesn't seem to work .. let me put it on fiddle

Comment: i've basically edited to .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset { float: none; right: .4em;} .4 or whatever value is given its doesnt work

Comment: You have to explicitly set the position (relative or absolute) if you want to use "left/right/top/bottom": `.ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset { float: none; position: relative; right: .4em;}` - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/ZdVrR/)

Answer (score 2):

Though the above answer is great, it applies to all the buttons. Below example is a modal dialog which can position each button separately and can style individually as well.

```
        $("#divModelPopup").dialog({
            closeOnEscape: false,
            width: 500,
            minWidth: 500,
            minHeight: 400,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
            title: "Terms & Conditions",
            buttons: {
                "I Decline": {
                    click: function () {
                        $(".lnkLogout").click();
                    },
                    text: "I Decline",
                    class: "btnDlgDecline"
                },
                "I Accept": {
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        // Update user details as accepted
                        $.ajax({
                        .... Ajax call
                        });
                    },
                    text: "I Accept",
                    class: "btnDlgAccept"
                },
                "Print": function () {
                    $("#divModelPopupPrintArea").printArea(options);
                }
            },
            resize: function (event, ui) {
                $("#divModelPopupScroll").height(ui.size.height / 1.27);
            }
        });
```

And then in CSS,

```
.btnDlgDecline{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    color: red !important;
}

.btnDlgAccept{
    color: green !important;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can change style of button within button tag.

```
                    Ok:{                                
                            style:"margin-right:640px",                               
                            click: function () {
                              //do something
                            }
                        },
```

This style is also work with multiple dialog.Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have three buttons and you want that they are distributed well on the line, try :

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    float: none;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    text-align: center; /* left/center/right */

}
.ui-button {
    margin-left: 5% !important;
    margin-right: 5% !important;
}
```

Be carefull, as someone said before, **important** is important

Enjoy,