# jQuery Dialog Close Button position change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI 1.10.x. I would like to move Close button to the right. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483930/custom-placement-of-buttons-in-dialog-box-jquery-ui

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in option for moving buttons.

You can achieve it by using your own style sheets (css).

---

See below css.

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    float: right;
}
```